# Tablix border inconsistent when zooming into ssrs report

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I'm using SSRS 2008 to create a report, the tablix border looks fine when the zoom level is 100%:[image]

But when I zoom in then the inner border becomes thicker:

[image]

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Zoom" uses a scaling effect to scale everything to a different size.  *Everything* is scaled, so that formatting is maintained - you don't get to pick and choose what scales, otherwise your reports formatting would quickly crumble - remember that SSRS formatting is relational, not absolute.

If you want your report to have large text with tiny borders, you need to design it that way - Zoom is not the feature you want.

Comment: I disagree, if you save the file as PDF it shows the inner borders as twice as thick. I think the problem is with SSRS generating the borders, not the "Zoom" view.